# How can I upload a file with progress bar?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have an Uploader with progress bar:

`index.php`:

```
<h1>Uploader</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
    <input type="file" name="image" >
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger cancel">Cancel</button>

    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
    </div>
</form>


<script>

    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);

        uploadImage($form);

    });

    function uploadImage($form){
        $form.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-success')
                                    .removeClass('progress-bar-danger');

        var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //progress event...
        request.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
            $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');
        });

        //progress completed load event
        request.addEventListener('load',function(e){
            $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completed....');
        });

        request.open('post', 'upload.php');
        request.send(formdata);

        $form.on('click','.cancel',function(){
            request.abort();

            $form.find('.progress-bar')
                .addClass('progress-bar-danger')
                .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
                .html('upload aborted...');
        });

    }

</script>
```

`upload.php`:

```
<?php

    $tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'files/'. $filename);

    echo "hello world";

?>
```

This is working so far very well.
But on `upload.php` I want to go on do more stuff. I simply try write `hello world`. But unfortunately I keep on being on `index.php` and I cannot see `hello world` anywhere.

Comment: just `exit` or `die` after end of the file upload.php

Comment: is the above done with AJAX? if so, then the echo is added to a return value that you can show using jQuery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219033/show-a-progress-on-multiple-file-upload-jquery-ajax

Comment: @RickusHarmse I used only the code from above. No Ajax

Comment: @MohdSayeed I did as you suggested, but unfortunately didn't change anything

Comment: @Jarla — The code above is packed full of Ajax

Comment: @Quentin Oh, I thought it is jquery. Never worked with Ajax

Comment: @Jarla — You're using the jQuery library and performing Ajax. Ajax just means using JavaScript to make an HTTP request without leaving the page.

Comment: @Quentin Ok, I understand. This could be the reason why I do not see "hello world". Because it is AJAX and I cannot leave the page

Comment: @Quentin It is good to know that this is Ajax. Now I can research how I can redirect to another page after loading is finished.